# insertRowsAtIndexPaths: crashes on first load

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

It doesnt happen every time, but randomly insertRowsAtIndexPaths: crashes my app on the tableviews endUpdates. Here is the code.

```
NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request1 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:JSON];

        NSMutableArray *indexArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self.contentArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id anObject, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            [indexArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection:0]];
        }];

        [self.mainTable beginUpdates];
        [self.mainTable insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.mainTable endUpdates];

        self.mainTable.tableFooterView = [self buildLoadingView];
        self.mainTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0, 0.0, 80.0, 0.0);
    });
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
    NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
}];
[operation start];
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of a crash is it, does the console provide any clues? You should initialize your *indexArray with the block specifier, e.g.: __block NSMutableArray *indexArray

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not increasing the returning number of rows, make sure to increase and decrease the number of rows that you are returning accordingly, inside below method.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return numberOfRowsinTableSection;

}
```

Comment: you are hero of the day